# Angular 2 - List of checkboxes - how to check the states of checkboxes

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I am using Angular 2 + Typescript, and I've just started for a short time. I want to make a list of checkboxes and check their states.

Like in some shopping websites, checkboxes are the companies, select some and press the search button to show the products of the selected companies.

```
<ul class="companies">
    <li *ngFor="let company of companies">
        <input type="checkbox">{{ companies.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

"companies" is an array taken from database. Each company simply has an id and a name. *ngFor will repeat the li for each element in the array. Each li contains a checkbox and a plain text.

I can't give each checkbox an id. Thus, I don't know how to check their states. I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a `mat-checkbox` you could use the `@Output() change: EventEmitter<MatCheckboxChange>` event call a method when the value state changes.  This would look something like this:

```
<ul class="companies">
    <li *ngFor="let company of companies">
        <mat-checkbox (change)="onCheckboxStateChange($event, company.id);">{{ companies.name }}</mat-checkbox>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you would need a `onCheckboxStateChange(changeEvent: MatCheckboxChange, id: number)` method in your ts class to handle the check event.  The `changeEvent` has a property `checked` which you can use as follows:

```
public onCheckboxStateChange(changeEvent: MatCheckboxChange, id: number) {
    const index = this.companies.findIndex(x => x.id === id);

    if (index === -1) {
        console.warn("Company not found");
        return;
    }

    companies[index].checked = changeEvent.checked;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I want to ask if the function findIndex is something that I have to make by myself?

Comment: Hi Thomas; the findIndex function is a prototype on arrays in typescript.  Please see here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: Sorry, not yet. At first, an error says it can't find the method findIndex. After I solved it somehow, another occurs. It says "cannot find name MatCheckboxChange".

Comment: To solve the cannot find name MatCheckboxChange you need to import MatCheckboxChange.  Alternatively you can change the type of changeEvent to `: any` and ti will work.